# Question about functions in $L^2$ space

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces, measurable-functions

Let $f,g \in L^2 (\mathbb{R})$. For $n \in \mathbb{N}$, define $f_n \in L^2(\mathbb{R})$ as $f_n(x) = f(x-n)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Prove that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\mathbb{R}} f_n g dm = 0$. ($m$ is a Lebesgue measure.)

I completely lose my way to solve this problem.

I thought that since we don't what $lim f_n(x)$ is, we need to bound the $\int_\mathbb{R}  f_n g dm$ to solve this problem.

But, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

- $g \in C^{\infty}_c(\mathbb{R})$, then you should be able to compute this limit
- approximate $g \in L^2$ with $g_n \in C^{\infty}_c$ by density

Comment: Could you explain more specifcally?

Comment: Immagine $f$ and $g$ are both $C^{\infty}_c$, then what happens? When $n$ goes to infinity you expect $f_n$ and $g$ to have disjoint support and your integral to be 0. When $f$ is in $L^2$ and $g\in C^{\infty}_c$, approximate $f$ with $f^{\epsilon} \in C^{\infty}_c \,:\, ||f-f^{\epsilon}||_{L^1}< \epsilon $ and write $\lim_{n}\int f_n g$ = $\lim_{n} \int  (f_n - f^{\epsilon}_n )g + \int f^{\epsilon} g$  and so on.